# Create Multiple Details on Array Data

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to create multi detail report based on data 1 row (Array Data)

Last time my report multi detail on multi row number , Now table design on Excel 1 row integrate Json Data

**Exam** 
[image]

```
SUB_SITE    LOCATION    RETURNED_DATE   REMARK  STATUS  Lines
Plot A  Pre-Commissioning   9/12/2016       RETURNED
```

> [{"BORROW_ID":1488,"CATEGORY_ID":926,"TAG_NO":"HHPP004","QTY":1.00,"CONDITION":60,"REMARK":"HHPP004-L0014","STATUS":"CLEAN"},{"BORROW_ID":1488,"CATEGORY_ID":926,"TAG_NO":"HHPP004","QTY":1.00,"CONDITION":60,"REMARK":"HHPP004-L0012","STATUS":"CLEAN"},{"BORROW_ID":1488,"CATEGORY_ID":918,"TAG_NO":"HHAD005","QTY":1.00,"CONDITION":60,"REMARK":"HHAD005-L0595","STATUS":"CLEAN"},{"BORROW_ID":1488,"CATEGORY_ID":918,"TAG_NO":"HHAD005","QTY":1.00,"CONDITION":60,"REMARK":"HHAD005-L0001","STATUS":"CLEAN"}]

Answer (score 0):

To show the details, you have to use sub reports. Right click on report, and insert Sub report, you can create a new one, or choose an previus report.